# How do I convert DTS packages to SSIS packages?

Tags: ssis, migration, dts

I'm looking for tutorials or walkthroughs for converting DTS packages into the new SSIS 2005. Any one knows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Migrating DTS Packages to Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768544.aspx)

SQL Server Integration Services provides a robust way to process millions of rows of data. The platform is highly extensible and performs much faster than the previous DTS platform. Migration of old DTS packages can be done two ways: through the built-in Package Migration Wizard, which handles simple package migrations; and through DTS xChange, which handles both simple and complex DTS migrations, while applying best practices to the migrated packages.

Answer (score 0):

within solution explorer there is a menu option to import DTS packages. This should do all the conversion for you. Having said that i've only ever tried it on simple packages

Answer (score 0):

Known DTS migration issues.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143462(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is so much better than DTS that I recommend rewriting your DTS packages as SSIS packages instead of migrating them. I recommend this especially for any DTS packages which needed to play games with dependencies in order to simulate looping or other features that DTS did not have.