# import data from dts to ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dts

I got asked to migrate DTS to SSIS.

As I've never seen this in my life, I started looking in [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1395/pass-dynamic-parameter-values-to-sql-server-integration-services/) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1084/dynamic-flat-file-connections-in-sql-server-integration-services/)!

This got me started but I still don't know how to integrate this and run it in my project.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial about DTS to SSIS migrations that can point it to me?

Thank you

Comment: This is too broad and/or recommend a tutorial question. You might be better off taking a stab at the project and ask anything specific that you get stuck on

Comment: Here's a duplicate:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258614/how-do-i-convert-dts-packages-to-ssis-packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you say `DTS to SSIS` three things come to my mind

1. You want to migrate a DTS package to SSIS.

for migration of DTS to SSIS, BIDS has `DTS Package Migration Wizard`. right-click the Packages folder and select Migrate DTS 2000 Packages to launch the DTS Package Migration Wizard as shown below:

[image]

2. you want to create a new package in SSIS to replace the DTS one.

well there is no silver bullet for this but you can start the migration tool to have a starting point or you will need to build a package from scratch.

3. you want to execute a DTS package from SSIS.

for this you have a control flow item called `Execute DTS 2000 Task`.

Comment: this got me going, thanx

Comment: down voter care to leave a comment ? maybe you can point me where I went wrong with this answer?